# How to convert raw image into signed 32 bit

Tags: java, hex, arrays, signed, endianness

I have a file created with dd command (raw file). I opened it with bless as shown in the image below:

[image: Bless]

Now I would like to extract the data from this file and get what appears under Signed 32 bit (If you see the image 84 is the number I want). Therefore, I want to convert the following string in this way:

```
10 00 00 00 --> 84
54 00 00 00 --> 70185301
```

In order to do this conversion I built the following program which opens the file, decode the line and write the result in a new file.

Here is the piece of code that does the extraction (@Duncan Helped me to create it):

```
try
  {
 
    File input = new File(inputFileField.getText());
    File output = new File(fileDirectoryFolder.getText() +"/"+ input.getName());

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8];         
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output)); 
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(input));

    int count = 0;        
    
    while (count < input.length() - 4) {

        in.readFully(buffer, 4, 4);
        String s= Long.toString(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong());
        out.writeBytes( s+ " ");        
        count += 4;
     }
   }
   System.out.println("Done"); 
     
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e1){}
```

However, the result I get is

```
10 00 00 00 --> 68719476736 
54 00 00 00 --> 360777252864
```

Do you understand where my problem is?

Thanks

Comment: does it work with BIG_ENDIAN?

Comment: Your first problem is that `10 00 00 00` hex in absolutely no way could ever become `84` decimal.  84d is 0x54. What you've got circled in the image is totally jumbled.

Comment: In bless you do not have `10 00 00 00` selected, look to the right of your "Signed 32-bit value" oval and you'll see the equivalent hex is given as `54 00 00 00`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So my question is how can I get that 84 out of my raw image? I am very confused... How can be ,therefore, that 84 come out from that selection (You say that is not, but I am quite sure it is selected) Maybe is bless my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s= 
Integer.toString(
   ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt());
```

Long has 8 bytes, you want to convert only 4.

And don't use an offset

```
in.readFully( buffer, 0, 4 );

$ echo $[0x1000000000]
68719476736
$ echo $[0x5400000000]
360777252864
```

This is due to the (incorrect) offset of 4 bytes when reading.

And another one, that should be corrected:

```
 while (count < input.length() - 3) {
```

Comment: So, you are using an int because I need only 4 bytes. Makes sense. I understand in.readFully( buffer, 0, 4 ); but I haven't understood why while (count < input.length() - 3) and count+=4

Comment: What, exactly, isn't clear? A Java int or Integer always has 32 bit, and long or Long has 64 bit. - readFull: see Javadoc. Also, see the explanation of the "big numbers" you've been getting.

Comment: Ahhhhh Got it, this is because you analyse a byte per time, right?

Comment: "a byte per time" isn't it, but I thought the -4 was there to safeguard against file lengths not being a multiple of 4. But then you should subtract 3 to get the correct limit. Subtract 4, and with a file length of 4*n the last 32 bit won't be converted.